# How to show popular blog post

Tags: php

I designed a blog and its retrieving data from database dynamically.Now i want that the blog that has most comments is displayed on the top. So anyone who can help me with this.I am posting the snapshots my page where the popular blogs is to be displayed.

Area where the popular blog are displayed.

http://s1272.photobucket.com/user/Ahad_Murtaza/media/Untitled_zps329dc86b.png.html

Comment: ORDER BY, for example `ORDER BY sum(comments) DESC`

Comment: sum() is a bulit-in function?

Comment: It is a built in SQL aggregate function. If you don't know what those are, I suggest you google and read, they are very important ;)

Comment: OK. But i am creating a function in different file and accessing in other file.I have two different tables i.e. blog and comment.the blog is linked to comment with blog_id. Can i use their ids to solve my prob?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AS i seen your images in link a query should be like this to display as per your output
Please set column name as per your need to display from table here is just query

```
select
  Comment.blog_id,
  count(Comment.commentId) as number_of_comments,blog.title
from
  Comment
LEFT JOIN blog
  ON Comment.blog_id=blog.blog_id
group by
  Comment.blog_id,
order by
  number_of_comments desc
limit 10;
```

let me know if i can help you more

Comment: I have function in one file and that function is called from other file.So, how can i get data to the variable for comments.

Comment: I am using php with dreamweaver and using XAAMP Server

Comment: if you are function is calling from different file then you have to return array from sql function to get in another file and then echo for output

Comment: can u give a small example plz.

Comment: http://www.w3resource.com/php/function/user-defined-function.php might be very usefull to you

Answer (score 1):

**Before asking try to do something or try to google it...**

**Your Answer**  **--**
You can use pagination for display the data...

Or you can do some query work --

```
SELECT SUM(something) AS fieldname
FROM tablename
ORDER BY fieldname
```

By taking that SUM of comments we can display.

Hope this will help !!